# Check if area contains only one entity in Minecraft with a command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to check if an area contains only one entity with command blocks. I've tried `/testfor`, but it activates the redstone for one person, even if there are more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/testfor @e` will output a signal strength based on how many entities it finds. For example, if 5 entities are found, the signal strength outputted will travel 5 blocks.

To test for exactly one entity, you can do something like this with and add on an AND gate:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can use another command block with the 'testforblock' command in it, testing for if the first command block has succeeded exactly once. The setup should look something like:

[image]

```
/testforblock X Y Z command_block 1 {SuccessCount:1}
```

Where X Y Z are the coordinates of the first command block, and the comparator should come off of this second command block.

Comment: So if I add an and gate it will find only one player and no more?

Comment: @user3189338 Yep. The repeater activates when there's one player, and the torch deactivates when there's two players, so both are on only when there's exactly one player.

Comment: One more question, if I want to check that the players are between specific bounds, how would I do that?

Comment: There's probably a way of doing this without the use of redstone dust, since [redstone dust is evil](http://moesh.ca/eliminate-redstone-dust/) when used with command blocks.

Comment: @user3189338 Put the bounds in the @e [selector arguments](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands#Target_selector_variables).

Comment: @MBraedley Execution order doesn't really matter in this case, it's going to be going into an AND gate. Unless there's also a compact way of doing this with command blocks, I don't think it's going to be causing many more block updates, if any, considering its size. Repeaters no longer cause lighting updates. Propagation lag is also most likely going to be less than it would be with command blocks, which would require a clock to activate rather than just updating when the entities in the area decrease/increase. I think redstone use for this situation is fine and possibly preferable.

Comment: @colorfusion: You're missing the point.  Redstone dust is evil because it causes lag.  Always.  The amount of lag might be small in this case, but it still exists and can (probably) be avoided.

Comment: @MBraedley Actually, after saying all of that, I've thought of a better solution to the one currently in my post which should be more compact. Lag can't "be avoided", but it should be slightly less now.

Comment: Yes, your second solution is (demonstrably) less laggy.  Redstone dust causes lag because it registers multiple block updates around it, and then those blocks register block updates.  One piece of redstone dust can register something like a thousand block updates _per redstone tick_.  Fill clocks produce 6 per filled redstone block.

Comment: @MBraedley A **thousand** bock updates?! I never thought it was that many just for one piece of dust for one tick. Is there a source on that? If there is, I'll probably be very careful to avoid any redstone dust in the future.

Comment: Okay, that might be a little hyperbolic, but suffice it to say that lag increase is exponential with redstone dust whereas it's only linear with fill clocks.